# Hibernate. Entity created in main thread isn't visible from child one

Tags: multithreading, hibernate, transactions

I found strange hibernate behavior and I cannot explain it.

If I create an object in default thread inside transaction and make manual flush
then I cannot find it in other thread.

If I create an object in one special thread with the same conditions then everything is all right.

Here is the code that I described above:

```
// transaction template with propagation required 
            ttNew.execute(new TransactionCallbackWithoutResult() {
                @Override
                protected void doInTransactionWithoutResult(TransactionStatus status) {
                    Assert.assertEquals(envStDao.getAll().size(), 0);
                    g = new Group();
                    g.setDescription("trial");
                       // in debugger I get id = 1
                    groupDao.save(g);

                    groupDao.flush();
                    accDao.flush();


                 }
                });

    // second stage right after the first - searching the group

   Thread t2 = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
        ttNew.execute(new TransactionCallbackWithoutResult() {
            @Override
            protected void doInTransactionWithoutResult(TransactionStatus status) {
            // here I get NULL!
            Group gg = groupDao.get(1);
        }
    });
        }
    });
    t2.start();
    t2.join();
```

If I wrap first block of the code into thread just as former I get the group.

Are any ideas?

I run above code in junit test. Dao objects use HibernateTemplate.

Comment: It seems the flush method doesn't work until thread termination pull some trigger. Sessions are bound to threads.

Comment: I think I found difference but not the root cause. If wrap two original blocks inside another thread it works again. The problem with JUnit. Its thread is special but why?

Answer (score 0):

Due to [transaction isolation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isolation_%28database_systems%29) you cannot see uncommitted data in another transaction. you have two different transaction here , so one cannot see uncommitted data of another.
The default isolationist is read committed. flush dosnt mean commit. commit will be done only at the end of the transaction. so when you flush the data in first transaction the data is written to the db , but doesn’t commit, so transaction 2 cannot see it.

Comment: Why do you think that my transaction is uncommited. I have two transactions and they are executed sequentially. I flush results. What did I wrong? What command should I add?

Comment: edit my answer , so take a look on the edited one to see if satisfy.